# how to get access token for fb page for 2 months or more

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi I had an access token for an facebook page.
I can get the access token for fb account but fb page it is getting only for one hour 
i had 7 fb pages in my account. So is there any process to get access token for 2 months or more

Comment: If you read [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension) you will notice that all tokens expire and have to be refreshed with user redirection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs give instructions for swapping a short-lived token for a long-lived token: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
2. Select your app from the dropdown on the top right hand side
3. Click "Get Access Token" button just below the application dropdown on the right hand side
4. In the dropdown select the page you want to get a access token for. If you don't see your pages listed then you'll need to make sure you're set with the admin role for the page. Also you may have to click "Get Page Access Token" in the dropdown, after which then your pages will show in the dropdown next time you click the "Get Access Token" button.
5. Click the blue exclamation point icon in the "Access token" input field
6. Click the "Open in Access Token Tool" button on the bottom right of the popup
7. Click the "Extend Access Token" button to get an token that never expires

"referance link:  https://www.rocketmarketinginc.com/blog/get-never-expiring-facebook-page-access-token/"